# 'No authorization header in request' when creating an event grid event from an Azure HTTPTrigger function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I've followed examples (few pages all similar) how to send an event to an event grid topic from an azure function in python but I get the following error:

> **No authorization header in the request**. Report '59dda51f-8df1-40ed-ac10-fc50cc9ec807:0:5/29/2023 1:04:46 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket. Status: 401 (No authorization header in the request. Report '59dda51f-8df1-40ed-ac10-fc50cc9ec807:0:5/29/2023 1:04:46 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.) ErrorCode: Unauthorized Content: { "error": { "code": "Unauthorized", "message": "No authorization header in the request. Report '59dda51f-8df1-40ed-ac10-fc50cc9ec807:0:5/29/2023 1:04:46 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket.", "details": [{ "code": "Unauthorized", "message": "No authorization header in the request. Report '59dda51f-8df1-40ed-ac10-fc50cc9ec807:0:5/29/2023 1:04:46 AM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket." }] } } Headers: Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED x-ms-request-id: 59dda51f-8df1-40ed-ac10-fc50cc9ec807 Date: Mon, 29 May 2023 01:04:46 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 517 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

I believe I've configured the event grid and the function to be anonymous:

1. The Event Grid Topic: Identity is Off and the "Local Authentication" is disabled
   2: The Azure function is an anonymous HTTP trigger (see below)
   3: The ENDPOINT and ACCESS KEY are correct and tested/verified

The HTTP Trigger looks like this (**init**.py):

```
import logging
import datetime
import os
import azure.functions as azfunc

def main( req: azfunc.HttpRequest
              , outputEvent: azfunc.Out[azfunc.EventGridOutputEvent]
              ) -> azfunc.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f"\nENDPOINT: {os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT')}")
    logging.info(f"\nKEY: {os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_KEY')}")

    event = azfunc.EventGridOutputEvent (
            id="1234",
            data={"tag1": "value1", "tag2": "value2"},
            subject="test-subject",
            event_type="test-event-1",
            event_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            data_version="1.0"
        )
    outputEvent.set(event)
    return azfunc.HttpResponse( body=f'Event Sent... {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}', status_code=200 )
```

The functions.json looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "{*routes}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventGrid",
      "name": "outputEvent",
      "topicEndpointUri": "EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT",
      "topicKeySetting": "EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_KEY",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far, aside from searching for examples I've tried a few different ways of sending the event, including by using the "EventGridPublisherClient" method (which only works on the local computer, not as an azure function). Also, I tried enabling managed identity but I need more research on it and it feels like I should be able to run the above without authentication.

What little I find that might help seems to be in C# or perhaps PowerShell but I find most examples look at consuming events from Event Grid so I'm hoping someone here has experience to share.

Comment: I tried with the same code and it worked fine locally as well as on Azure. Can you add some snapshots of the test of the API call and the result? I'm assuming you are doing it from postman and that there is no API gateway in the middle.

Comment: I think I spotted the issue - I created two event grid topics, one with local authentication enabled, another with it disabled. If it's enabled it works, if it's disabled I get the error. I'm going to do to more testing but this must have happened by accident/mistake because it works using the default value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is coming when you are trying to call the http function and not during its actual execution to send the Event to the Event grid.

Check what is the authentication set on the Azure function. On the Azure function, click on Authentication on the left panel under Settings. If you see any setting here, it means the person who created the function expects you to send a bearer Token when calling the http endpoint. I would suggest you contact the person who did this settings for the client credentials. If you can deactivate this so it looks like the below, the function can be called without any authorization header.
[image]

To verify this, you can try creating a default boiler plate http triggered function (exclude any output binding). Now try and trigger this function. If you receive the same error, it confirms my assumption.

An anonymous function just means that there is no need for an API key in the url. It has nothing to do with the AD authentication which I spoke of above.

Comment: The authentication settings look the same for me. The function works as is, that is, if I comment out the "outputEvent.set(event)" then I get no error.

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduced the reported issue in my environment and got the below results**-

I have created an azure Http triggered function to send the event to event grid topic wherein System Identity status is set to **off** and the function is an **anonymous** HTTP trigger function.

[image]

**Prerequisite**-

```
pip install azure-eventgrid
pip install azure-functions
```

**Code** -

****init**.py file**-

```
import  logging
import  json
import  datetime
import  requests
import  azure.functions  as  func
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
event_data  = [ {
"id": "127",
"subject": "Event Published successfully",
"data": {
"tag1": "12345",
"tag2": "6789"
},
"eventType": "test-event-1",
"eventTime": datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
"dataVersion": "1.0"
}]
logging.info(event_data)
topic_endpoint  =  "< your topic endpoint >"
topic_key  =  "< Event grid topic key >"
headers  = {
"Content-type": "application/json",
"aeg-sas-key": topic_key
}
response  =  requests.post(topic_endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(event_data))
if  response.status_code  ==  200:
return  func.HttpResponse("Event sent successfully")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Failed to send event: {response.text}")
```

**function.json file**-

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"entryPoint": "main",
"bindings": [
{
"authLevel": "anonymous",
"type": "httpTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"name": "req",
"methods": [
"post"
]
},
{
"type": "http",
"direction": "out",
"name": "$return"
}
]
}
```

**VS Code**-

[image]

**Postman**-

[image]

**Output**-

[image]

**Azure Portal**-

**Before Event sent**-

[image]

**After Event sent**-

[image]

Comment: Interesting, you are not using the azure-eventgrid module to send the response, is that wise? No parameter out binding - didn't know this was possible but feels like this will cause issues later. I will try this, if only to see it work :-)

Comment: Even though this works, this is not advisable as we already have an SDK to abstract all the  heavy lifting for us. An example is retries which are built into the SDK.